# conflicting valus for Signed-by while trying to install the lastest version of R on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt

I try to install the lastest version of R on my Ubuntu 22.04.3. For that I need to run first `sudo apt-get update` but in the output I have Signed-By conflict issues :

```
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/ jammy-cran40/: /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/marutter_pubkey.gpg != /usr/share/keyrings/r-project.gpg
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I try to remove it :

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/marutter_pubkey.gpg
```

but it couldn't be removed

```
rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/marutter_pubkey.gpg': No such file or directory

cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/r-project.list

deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/r-project.gpg] https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/
# deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/r-project.gpg] https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/
```

is the `ppa:marutter/rrutter4.0` installed?

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep marutter/rrutter4.0

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/ jammy-cran40/: /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/marutter_pubkey.gpg != /usr/share/keyrings/r-project.gpg

E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I really don't know what to do. please help

Comment: Show the output of your sources file where you added the R repositories?

Comment: Do you also have the PPA `ppa:marutter/rrutter4.0` installed?  Michael Rutter maintains a different PPA for R.

Comment: i don't, I'm gonna try to install it now

Comment: well actually, I'm not sure if it's install or not. The thing is that I already try to follow many other forums command line before asking here, so I know that I did installit at some point but I though that I removed it. I let my output on my script